# Eclipse/nsight formatter doesn't respect function body indentation policy

Tags: eclipse, cuda, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting, autoformatting

I use CUDA 8.0's version of nsight (Eclipse platform 4.4.0, CDT 8.4.0).  My Eclipse C/++ formatter is configured to indent as follows (image is from the Formatter config prev:

[image]

but if I have this code:

[image]

and I press enter, get to the next line (the cursor is placed under the `span`), and type in an opening brace, it is not placed at the beginning of the line, but is rather kept indented:

[image]

Is this a bug or have I misconfigured something?

**Notes:**

- I tried both the built-in formatter and the "CUDA C" formatter; they behave the same in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this behaviour in stock CDT as well. It looks like a bug. Please [file a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks.

Comment: After creating an account, and trying to log into the bugzilla, I get a message saying "Either no products have been defined to enter bugs against or you have not been given access to any." ; perhaps you could link to someplace explaining how exactly one files bugs there?

Comment: @einpoklum Quote from the website: "Due to SPAM if you are a *NEW* user and wish to file bugs you will need to contact webmaster at eclipse dot org to be granted permission. All other users should be unaffected by this change." As a good, kind (but biased) advice: if you care about your sanity, do not use Eclipse or any products based on it unless it is really really unique piece of software you cannot live without (Nsight Eclipse Edition does not fall into this category; NVVP, well... maybe).

Comment: @Drop: I try to ignore Eclipse's deeper pits; but - if you have other recommendations I'm open to them, I suppose. Although perhaps that would more approprirate for chat.

Comment: @einpoklum: I filed a bug for you: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511144.

Comment: @einpoklum: Note also that running the formatter (`Ctrl+Shift+F` or `Source -> Format`) does fix the indentation of the braces.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Yes, I know that; it's part of the reason this puzzled me. Thanks.